# Pulling a random item from an array on a timer

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nstimer

I have an array of strings. I would like to display 3 unique items from this array randomly. Then every 5 seconds, one of the items gets replaced with another unique item (my idea here is adding an animation with a delay).

I can display the 3 strings, however sometimes they repeat, and the timer is not updating the factLabel label.

Here's my progress:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateUI()
}

func randomFact() -> String {
    let arrayCount = model.cancunFacts.count
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayCount)))
    return model.cancunFacts[randomIndex]
}

// Display the facts
func updateUI() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(randomFact), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    factLabel.text = randomFact() + " " + randomFact() + " " + randomFact()
}
```

**How do I get the text to always update randomly, without the 3 facts repeating?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of indexes. Remove a random index from the array, use it to index into your strings. When the array of indexes is empty, refill it.

Here is some sample code that will generate random, non-repeating strings:

```
var randomStrings = ["Traitor", "Lord Dampnut", "Cheeto-In-Chief", 
  "F***face Von Clownstick", "Short-Fingered Vulgarian", 
  "Drumpf", "Der Gropenführer", "Pumpkin in a suit"]

var indexes =  [Int]()

func randomString() -> String {
    if indexes.isEmpty {
        indexes = Array(0...randomStrings.count-1)
    }
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(indexes.count)))
    let randomIndex = indexes.remove(at: index)
    return randomStrings[randomIndex]
}

for i in 1...100 {
    print (randomString())
}
```

(Note that it may still generate repeating strings in the case when the array of indexes is empty and it needs to be refilled. You'd need to add extra logic to prevent that case.)

### Version 2:

Here is the same code, modified slightly to avoid repeats when the array of indexes is empty and needs to be refilled:

```
var randomStrings = ["tiny-fingered", "cheeto-faced", "ferret-wearing", "sh*tgibbon"]

var indexes =  [Int]()
var lastIndex: Int?

func randomString() -> String {
    if indexes.isEmpty {
        indexes = Array(0...randomStrings.count-1)
    }
    var randomIndex: Int
    repeat {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(indexes.count)))
        randomIndex = indexes.remove(at: index)
    } while randomIndex == lastIndex
    lastIndex = randomIndex
    return randomStrings[randomIndex]
}


for i in 1...10000 {
    print (randomString())
}
```

Even though it's using a repeat...while statement, the repeat condition will never fire twice in a row, because you'll never get a repeat except right after refilling the array of indexes.

With that code, if there is a repeat, the selected string will be skipped on that pass through the array. To avoid that, you'd need to adjust the code slightly to not remove a given index from the array until you verify that it is not a repeat.

### Version 3:

Version 2, above, will skip an entry if it picks a repeat when it refills the array. I wrote a 3rd version of the code that refills the array, removes the last item it returned so that it can't repeat, and then adds it back to the array once it's picked a random item. This third version will always return every item in the source array before refilling it and will also never repeat an item. Thus it's truly random with no bias:

```
import UIKit

var randomStrings = ["Traitor", "Lord Dampnut", "Cheeto-In-Chief",
                     "F***face Von Clownstick", "Short-Fingered Vulgarian",
                     "Drumpf", "Der Gropenführer", "Pumpkin in a suit"]

var indexes =  [Int]()
var lastIndex: Int?
var indexToPutBack: Int?

func randomString() -> String {
  
  //If our array of indexes is empty, fill it.
  if indexes.isEmpty {
    indexes = Array(0...randomStrings.count-1)
    print("") //Print a blank line each time we refill the array so you can see
    
    //If we have returned an item previously, find and remove that index
    //From the refilled array
    if let lastIndex = lastIndex,
      let indexToRemove = indexes.index(of: lastIndex) {
      indexes.remove(at: indexToRemove)
      indexToPutBack = indexToRemove //Remember the index we removed so we can put it back.
    }
  }
  var randomIndex: Int
  let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(indexes.count)))
  randomIndex = indexes.remove(at: index)
  
  //If we refilled the array and removed an index to avoid repeats, put the removed index back in the array
  if indexToPutBack  != nil{
    indexes.append(indexToPutBack!)
    indexToPutBack = nil
  }
  lastIndex = randomIndex
  return randomStrings[randomIndex]
}


for i in 1...30 {
  print (randomString())
}
```

Sample output:

```
Short-Fingered Vulgarian
F***face Von Clownstick
Pumpkin in a suit
Drumpf
Lord Dampnut
Traitor
Der Gropenführer
Cheeto-In-Chief

Der Gropenführer
Drumpf
Lord Dampnut
Short-Fingered Vulgarian
Cheeto-In-Chief
Pumpkin in a suit
Traitor
F***face Von Clownstick

Short-Fingered Vulgarian
F***face Von Clownstick
Drumpf
Traitor
Cheeto-In-Chief
Lord Dampnut
Pumpkin in a suit
Der Gropenführer

Lord Dampnut
Short-Fingered Vulgarian
Pumpkin in a suit
Cheeto-In-Chief
Der Gropenführer
F***face Von Clownstick
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timer is calling random fact, which simply returns a fact and doesn't do anything. You should probably have some third method called initializeTimer that does the Timer.scheduledtimer, which you should take out of your updateUI method.  That timer should call updateUI.  This would fix your labels updating. Also you would call initializeTimer in your viewDidLoad instead of updateUI. As far as preventing the repetition of facts, Duncan C's idea of having a separate array that you remove items from as you set new random facts then fill back up when it's empty seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easiest to maintain two arrays, `usedStrings` and `unusedStrings`, of random strings, like this:

```
var unusedStrings: [String] = ["king", "philip", "calls", "out", "for", "good", "soup"]
var usedStrings: [String] = []

func randomString() -> String {
    if unusedStrings.isEmpty() {
        unusedStrings = usedStrings
        usedStrings = []
    }

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(unusedStrings.count))
    let randomString = unusedStrings[randomIndex]
    usedStrings.append(randomString)

    return randomString
}
```